# MSBuild calling the Package Target of Web Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Does anyone know the components that need to be installed in order to make the `Package` Target available via MSBuild.

It's possible to `Package` using MSBuild on a machine with Visual Studio installed, but not on a build server with only the .NET 4 SDK and Web Deploy 2.0 installed, which results in the following error:

```
msbuild "Package" does not exist in the project.
```

It partly comes down to the following missing files on the server:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\*.*
```

This can of course be resolved by copying the contents of the MSBuild VisualStudio folder to the equivalent directory on the build server, but this is not a manageable solution for server configuration.

All the answers I've read involve having Visual Studio installed or copying the files. Surely it's possible to compile the Web Deploy package without installing Visual Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a TeamCity CI server without VS installed building a Web Project configured to also create a deployment package on successful build. However, for the life of me I can't recall if I copied those files manually or if they were installed by some component.

The relevant components I have installed are the following, if you want to give it a shot:

1. .NET 4.0 SDK;
2. [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Integrated) Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=115);
3. [Visual Studio 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2680); (Not the VS 2010 SDK SP1)
4. [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Visualization & Modeling SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23025);
5. Web Deploy 2.0;

I installed the VS Shell in order to be able to install the VS 2010 SDK which in turn was required in order to install the Visualization & Modeling SDK so that I was able to run T4 transformations on the build server.

With this components and configuring the following MSBuild properties `DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package` to create the deploy package I had no problems, but as I said earlier I may have copied the files manually after giving up all hope of finding a more cleaner solution and now my brain is blocking any memory of such ill action.

Comment: Thanks Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell seems to have done the trick.